# What IAM permissions do I need to use to create a Service Account similar to Default Compute Engine Service Account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, service-accounts

I've deleted the default service account and it has been longer than 30 days. I don't know if it applies to all marketplace solutions, but the one that I want to use can't be launched without the compute engine default service account.

What are the IAM permissions I need to set to create a service account that has the same permissions as the compute engine default service account to launch VM from marketplace?

I tried Compute Admin, compute.imageUser and Compute Instance Admin, but to no avail.

In addition to that, why does the marketplace solution require the default service account when it is recommended to disable/remove the default compute engine service account because of the editor role?

Comment: On which page did you delete the service account? On the IAM page or on the service account page?

Comment: 1) The Compute Engine Service Account is just like any other service account. Create a new service account with the roles you require and assign to your Compute Engine VM instance. This is actually a recommended procedure (to create a new service account). The default role assigned is **Editor**, which is not recommended to use. 2) By using the default compute engine service account, the process of creating a marketplace product is a bit easier, requires fewer permissions from the end-user, and less documentation that might require technical support.

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere I can't remember. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: Thanks as always @JohnHanley I tried to recreate the Default Compute Engine SA with the same naming syntax and Editor role but unable to launch the marketplace solution with success. It will take more than 30 minutes to spin up the VM followed by an error message `{"ResourceType":"runtimeconfig.v1beta1.waiter","ResourceErrorCode":"504","ResourceErrorMessage":"Timeout expired."} ` I'mnot sure if it is only applicable to the solution that I am trying to use. For learning curiosity, I wonder why it is not mandatory to disallow Default Compute Engine SA for marketplace solutions?

Comment: 1) You cannot manually create a service account with the same name as the default name. 2) Have you tried **gcloud beta iam service-accounts undelete**? 3) If you have no other compute services running (GCE, Run, etc), disable the **compute engine API** (compute.googleapis.com). Then reenable the API. This will recreate the service account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is the compute engine default service account?**

By default, the account is automatically granted the **project editor role** on the project and is listed in the IAM section of Cloud Console. This service account is only deleted when the project is deleted. However, you can change the roles granted to this account, including revoking all access to your project.

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#default_service_account)

Comment: Thanks! Recreating the SA with the editor role doesn't work in my case. I tried to recreate the Default Compute Engine SA with the same naming syntax and Editor role but unable to launch the marketplace solution with success. It will take more than 30 minutes to spin up the VM followed by an error message `{"ResourceType":"runtimeconfig.v1beta1.waiter","ResourceErrorCode":"504","ResourceErrorMessage":"Timeout expired."} `

Answer (score 0):

You can undelete a service account only if it is deleted fewer than 30 days ago.

Instead of that, we can [create a new service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating) and grant an ‘Editor’ role to it, as a default compute engine service account has the same role by default. Refer to *[Compute Engine default service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#default_service_account)* for more information.

To set the service account as the compute engine default service account on the project, we can use the following [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/project-info/set-default-service-account):

```
gcloud alpha compute project-info set-default-service-account
```

But since the command is in the ‘alpha’ [launch stage](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages), it is not available for everyone.

I could suggest the following options:

1. [Create a new project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project).
2. Request an Alpha feature that allows setting a new service account as the compute engine default service account.

If you have questions regarding an Alpha release or participation in an Alpha program, please reach out to [sales](https://cloud.google.com/contact/). In this case a sales team needs to approve it.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the input. Sorry to have copy and paste the same reply -- Recreating the SA with the editor role doesn't work in my case. I tried to recreate the Default Compute Engine SA with the same naming syntax and Editor role but unable to launch the marketplace solution with success. It will take more than 30 minutes to spin up the VM followed by an error message `{"ResourceType":"runtimeconfig.v1beta1.waiter","ResourceErrorCode":"504","ResourceErrorMessage":"Timeout expired."} `

Comment: @FlyingPenguin I modified my answer. Check my new answer.